# Boost.Python - problem wrapping C++ overloaded operator

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

Using Boost.Python, I am trying to wrap a operator overload method "+".

I have got the following class from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm:

```
 class Box {
   public:
      double getVolume(void) {
         return length * breadth * height;
      }
      void setLength( double len ) {
         length = len;
      }
      void setBreadth( double bre ) {
         breadth = bre;
      }
      void setHeight( double hei ) {
         height = hei;
      }

      Box operator+(const Box& b) {
         Box box;
         box.length = this->length + b.length;
         box.breadth = this->breadth + b.breadth;
         box.height = this->height + b.height;
         return box;
      }


   private:
      double length;      // Length of a box
      double breadth;     // Breadth of a box
      double height;      // Height of a box
};
```

However, when I try to wrap the overloaded operator using the following:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;


  python::class_<Box>("Box")  
    .def("setLength",  &Box::setLength )
    .def("setBreadth", &Box::setBreadth)
    .def("setHeight",  &Box::setHeight )
    .def("getVolume",  &Box::getVolume )
    .def(self + Box()); 

}
```

I get this error:

**test.cpp:47:10: error: ‘self’ was not declared in this scope
     .def(self + Box());**

According to https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html#python.class_operators_special_functions I cannot find what I am doing wrong.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

OS: Fedora 29 - 64 bit.

Comment: Did you try `python::self`? (Also should be `python::self + python::self`)

Comment: Thanks! That worked!